# Correct design for querying DB through out the app

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

I want to use sqlite driver for my java application that I am developing with netbeans. What would be the correct "design" when it comes to integrating DB queries?

Basically should I create a static variable holding the connection which I can use to execute SQL statements through out the app? Or should I create the connection everytime I want to do the query?

Here is my code

```
  Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); 
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Mydb.db");
    st = conn.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(/*My sql statement*/);
```

Thank you

Comment: I usually use **Singleton Design Pattern** to only have one instance of connection available in my app. And usually my connection to the database remains open as long as my application(mostly desktop applicaion) is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating connection every time you write a query is not a good approach because it will be an overload on database for handling multiple connections. 

Rather you should prefer a method or a class which would return you an instance of database connectivity.